# Convert DICOM to TIFF

Tags: python, dicom, pydicom

I'm new to Python so forgive my ignorance If I don't have all the info correct. I'm trying raster through a directory and convert all the DICOM files within to TIFF files. I have gotten the search functionality to work, but I am having a hard time saving the images as TIFFs. I'm using the pydicom libraries to read in the DICOM and manipulate the header information. Also, I have tried using the save_as function in pydicom to save to TIFF, but I would rather use the save function in PIL to properly set the compression of the TIFF. I think the problem is that I can't/don't understand how to extract the actual image data from a DICOM and place it in a new image.Any Help would be greatly appreciated ... Cheers

Python 2.7
PIL 1.1.7
Pydicom 0.9.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to use `PIL` to save image data as `.tiff`, [this example](http://code.google.com/p/pydicom/source/browse/source/dicom/contrib/pydicom_PIL.py) should help you to pass image data from `pydicom` to `PIL` (there is more [here in the comments](http://code.google.com/p/pydicom/wiki/ViewingImages#Using_pydicom_with_Python_Imaging_Library_%28PIL%29)).

Comment: That worked out great ... I used the frombuffer command and it allowed me to save the dicom pixel data to tiff. Now, it seems as if it has inverted all pixel intensities. I used a "I;16" mode rather than the "L". Is there a way to keep the intensity the same?

Comment: @Masrawy, unfortunately I can't help you with this one (at least right now).

Comment: Thanks for help, you at least got me started on the right path. Cheers.

Comment: This is what I used to save the DICOM to TIFF:
import dicom  
import Image  

meta=dicom.read_file("dicomimage.dcm")   
TT=Image.frombuffer("L",imSize,meta.PixelData,"raw","",0,1)  
TT.save("testOUTPUT.tiff","TIFF",compression="none") 

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Found an answer online to the same query sometime back, although I don't remember the site but as I applied it to my code, sharing it here for others as well :

```
 import pylab
 import dicom
 ImageFile=dicom.read_file(<SourceFilePath>) #Path to "*.dcm" file
 pylab.imshow(ImageFile.pixel_array,cmap=pylab.cm.bone) #to view image
```

or if you want to save the image then instead use:
     `pylab.imsave('<DestinationFilePath>',ImageFile.pixel_array,cmap=pylab.cm.bone)`

The `imsave` will by default save the image in *.png* format though. You can specify the desired format in the `imsave()` if it is supported.

Hope it is useful.